# Can new File() constructor return null on Android?

Tags: java, android

I saw this code in android training center website:

```
boolean hasExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
    // Get path for the file on external storage.  If external
    // storage is not currently mounted this will fail.
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");
    if (file != null) {
        return file.exists();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does that mean that on Android `new File()` can return null?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 13):

No, a constructor may never return null. A constructor either returns a fully initialised object or throws an exception or error.

Comment: So I guess this is a typo in Android guides.

Comment: Or someone who confused Java with Visual C++